# Kendo UI: How to change background color of KendoDropDown List using template

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo dropdown which gets populated fine. One requirement is to highlight the background red of an item if the item is coming back is IsActive to false using template. Below is the code I came up with so far.

```
 var carsDropDown = $("#ddlCars").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "DisplayValue",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        valuePrimitive: true,
        optionLabel: " ",
        dataSource: intakeView.viewModel.carsDataSource,
        template: '#= !data.IsActive ? \'<span style="background-color:redBackGroundColor"></span>\' : "" #'
    });
```

CSS:

```
.redBackGroundColor {
    background-color: red;   
}
```

The above code is graying out all the dropdown options including the selected option. I would like to only change background color of options which are coming back is IsActive to False.

Comment: Any chance you want `class="redBackGroundColor"` instead of `style="redBackGroundColor"`?

Comment: If not - add some working example (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: @Dekel changing it to class did not help

Comment: So know is the time to add working example :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use class not style as Dekel indicates. Second, you may want to consider changing foreground color, not background color since the background color will be gray on hover. You also need to add the description to your template. Something like this should work:

```
var carsDropDown = $("#ddlCars").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "DisplayValue",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    valuePrimitive: true,
    optionLabel: " ",
    dataSource: intakeView.viewModel.carsDataSource,
    template: '<span class=\"k-state-default #= IsActive ? "" : "redBackGroundColor" #\">#: DisplayValue #</span>'
});
```

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template

Comment: this is perfect. but if i wanna play with background color then what class should i play with

Comment: Classes are defined by you. You have a class called redBackGroundColor that will indeed change the background color to red. So the code above will apply that to inactive elements.

Comment: The above code changes the foreground color. I wanna change the background color instead.

Comment: I tried this '<span class=\"k-state-default #= data.IsActive ? "" : style="background-color:redBackGroundColor" #\">#: DisplayValue #</span>' but it didnt work

Comment: You can't add a style within a class. Your end result would be <span class="k-state-default style="background-color:redBackGroundColor"> which is not legal html. [Kendo hash syntax](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) can be tricky.